# I can access the API data, but won't display it in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I used the API from https://api-berita-indonesia.vercel.app/suara/health, I tried fetching using JavaScript and linking it to my HTML page, and when I checked in the console, I could get the API data, but can't display it.

[image: This is my page]

This is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Articles | ParentCare</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top py-4 bgcolor" data-aos="fade-down">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../index.php">Parent<span>Care</span></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../../index.php">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="article.php">Artikel</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="../FAQ/faq.php">FAQ</a>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Layanan
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Transaksi/konsultasi.php">Konsultasi</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../Tes Mental Health/tes-mental-health.php">Tes Kesehatan Mental</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="../Forum Discussion/forum.php">Discuss</a>
                        <a class="nav-login btn btn-success px-4 text-white btn-login" id="login" href="../login.php">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Article -->
    <section class="article">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="col-12" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="100">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">ARTICLE</h2>
                    <p class="subheading">Baca artikel kesehatan unggulan kami
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <form action="">
                <div class="row mt-4">
                    <div class="col-10"><input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search for article" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="200"></div>
                    <div class="col-2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-send search-btn" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="200"><span> Search </span><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button></div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="news-container" class="row" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="200">
            </div>
            <main>
                <div id="news-container" class="row" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="200">
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Article -->
    <!-- Footer -->
    <section class="footer mt-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-3">
                    <div class="logo-footer">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ParentCare.</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info mt-lg-2">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <a href="" class=" infotxt">Layanan
                                    konsultasi anak terbaik untuk anda</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sosmed mt-lg-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <a href="https://wa.me/6282133635122" target="_blank" class="infotxt"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1">

                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="info mt-4">
                        <h3>About ParentCare</h3>
                        <div class="footer-list mt-lg-3">
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">Tentang Kami</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">Hubungi Kami</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">ParentCare Happy</a></li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="info mt-4">
                        <h3>Kerja Sama</h3>
                        <div class="footer-list mt-lg-3">
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">Info Kolaborasi</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">Mahasiswa</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">Komunitas</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">Sekolah</a></li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="info mt-4">
                        <h3>More</h3>
                        <div class="footer-list mt-lg-3">
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">Syarat & Ketentuan</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">Privasi</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-footer" href="#">Iklan</a></li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mt-4">
                    <p class="copyright">Copyright © 2022 ParentCare | All Rights Reserved.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Footer -->

    <script src="fetch newsapi.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my JavaScript to fetching the API:

```
let DATA = {};
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const newsContainer = document.querySelector('#news-container');

async function getData() {
    console.log('Start fetching data from the API...');

    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            'https://api-berita-indonesia.vercel.app/suara/health/'
        );
        DATA = await response.json();

        console.log('Data from API retrieved successfully:', DATA);

        if (newsContainer === null) {
            console.error('HTML element with id "news-container" not found!');
            return;
        }

        for (const article of DATA.data) {
            newsContainer.innerHTML += templateNews(article);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}


form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    let filteredNews = null;
    const inputSearch = event.srcElement[0];

    // console.log(event);
    for (const article of DATA.data) {
        filteredNews = DATA.data.filter((item) => {
            return item.posts.title === inputSearch.value;
        });
    }

    newsContainer.innerHTML = '';
    for (const article of filteredNews) {
        newsContainer.innerHTML += templateNews(article);
    }
});

function templateNews(data) {
    let image = '';
    if (data.posts.thumbnail !== null) {
        image = `<img src="${data.posts.thumbnail}" alt="">`;
    }

    return `
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="news-item">
        <div class="card">
            ${image}
            <a href="${data.posts.link}" class="mt-5">
                <h6>${data.posts.title}</h6>
            </a>
            <p class="article-categories">${data.posts.description}</p>
            <p class="article-time">${data.posts.pubDate}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    `;
}

getData();
```

And this is my console looks like, I can get the API data

[image]

I hope I can display the API data for my article page.

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the posts rather than the top-level data? You didn't actually explain what bit of the data you're trying to display

Comment: Yes I tried to loop.
So I want to create an article website where all article data is obtained from the API which has the link https://api-berita-indonesia.vercel.app/voice/health , previously I used https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=id&category=health&apiKey=fab180adfd804228917c512c4599d0d4 with almost the same javascript structure and can display on the page
But when I tried the latest API, I couldn't display it even though I used the correct property to get some posts

Comment: `Yes I tried to loop`...yes but my point was you might be looping through the wrong property of your object. You're trying to loop `data`, which isnt a list. `Posts` looks like a list, so I'd guess you should loop that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your logs your `DATA.data` is not an array - it's an object.

That's why your for..of loops will not work that way.

Because object is not iterable.

```
for (const article of DATA.data) {
    filteredNews = DATA.data.filter((item) => {
        return item.posts.title === inputSearch.value;
    });
}
```

That for loop will not work. More info on for..of [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

But there is also an option to iterate on object keys with for..in.
More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Seems like you would like to get some property of your `DATA.data` object and do some logic with it.

For example, you can get your posts with `DATA.data.posts` and iterate on them.

Comment: I have changed DATA.data to an array with the syntax Array.from() . 
        
`const DATAArray = Array.from(DATA.data);

for (const article of DATAArray) {
    newsContainer.innerHTML += templateNews(article);
}`

And I don't have an error anymore on my console, but still can't show the API data on the page

Comment: It will not work that way. Your DATA.data contains ONE object, which has `posts` property with 100 items inside. If your want to get access to `posts` property, then you have to use `DATA.data.posts` and it would be your array of posts.

Comment: I have done that, but the data displayed is undefined

Comment: Could you please drop the code snippet?

Comment: Ah, I just can display it only with `data`, for example `data.description` . Thanks for your helping :)